# Align text/link horizontally with a responsive image below

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, alignment

I have a bunch of `div`s vertically stacked together in a responsive layout. The top one contains a text, while the second one below has a centered image with a blue background (whose max width is constrained by its parent `div`'s height). I've added some background colors to highlight the boundaries of `div`s in question.

[image]

I want to align the top text **always to the right side edge of the image**, *regardless of the size/width of image that responds to the window/screen size change*. At the moment, the text is aligned to the rightmost edge of its parent `div`.

What's the cleanest way to do so? By cleanest, I mean with the best compatibility across modern browsers (>2016) and without affecting the rest of page elements.

Relevant html:

```
<div class="row" id="top_row">
    <div class="column" id="header_div">
        <p class="top_text">Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="image_row">
    <div class="column" id="image_div">
        <img class="image_content" src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#header_div, #image_div, #long_text_div, #short_text_div, #bottom_text_div {
    height: inherit;
    text-align: center;
}

.top_text {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 0.83vmax;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 60%;
    transform: translateY(-40%);
}

.image_content {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Full [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amarofiddle/qkcpsv02/) linked.

Comment: I can do it, but would it be okay for you to have js?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov thanks, is a html/css solution possible here? If not, I'd prefer a JS solution without using an external library

Comment: in order to solve your problem with the help of css and html, you need to change the structure of the html. I already have a solution for you, but I was waiting for your answer. My code doesn't contain external libraries.

Comment: I have given you a solution. In fact, the `resize` listener (`window.addEventListener ("resize", f_width);`) can be removed since there is a `load` listener. I made a `resize` listener for you for an illustrative example. But if the resizing of the picture will take place in real time, then the `resize` listener must be left in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can encapsulate both the image and the text in the same `div`, leaving both as a `display: block` and, if necessary, use a `margin-top: -50px` to reposition as it is in the image. This is the cleanest way to align without having to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

In my example, dynamically calculating the width of the bottom image, then assigning the width to the top content. Also, you need to add two rules to the `#top_row` container, like this:

```
#top_row {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #A5DEF4;
 
  display: flex; /*add this it*/
  justify-content: center; /*add this it*/   
}
```

Was it necessary?

```js
function f_width() {  
  let header_div = document.querySelector('#header_div');
  let image_div = document.querySelector('.image_content').offsetWidth;
   
  header_div.style.width = image_div + 'px';   
}

window.addEventListener("load", f_width);
window.addEventListener("resize", f_width);
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    background: #E5E7E9;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.column {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#top_row {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #A5DEF4;
 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;  
}
#image_row {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #BDC0BA;
}
#text_row_1 {
  height: 7vh;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#text_row_2 {
  height: 3vh;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#bottom_row {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header_div, #image_div, #long_text_div, #short_text_div, #bottom_text_div {
    height: inherit;
    text-align: center;
}

.top_text {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 0.83vmax;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 60%;
    transform: translateY(-40%);
}

.image_content {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.text_content {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1vmax;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding-left: 30pt;
    padding-right: 30pt;
}

.bottom_content {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 0.67vmax;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css">
        <title>Test test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="top_row">
                <div class="column" id="header_div">
                     <p class="top_text">Some text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="image_row">
                <div class="column" id="image_div">
                    <img class="image_content" src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="text_row_1">
                <div class="column" id="long_text_div">
                    <div class="text_content">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="text_row_2">
                <div class="column" id="short_text_div">
                    <div class="text_content">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="bottom_row">
                <div class="column" id="bottom_text_div">
                    <div class="bottom_content">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

solution without js (take a look at the problem).

You need to do it like this:

```
.column {
  width: inherit;
 /* float: left;*/
}
```

And add this to css:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    background: #E5E7E9;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.row {    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  width: inherit;
 /* float: left;*/
}

#top_row {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #A5DEF4;
}
#image_row {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #BDC0BA;
}
#text_row_1 {
  height: 7vh;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#text_row_2 {
  height: 3vh;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#bottom_row {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header_div, #image_div, #long_text_div, #short_text_div, #bottom_text_div {
    height: inherit;
    text-align: center;
}

.top_text {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 0.83vmax;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 60%;
    transform: translateY(-40%);
}

.image_content {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.text_content {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1vmax;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding-left: 30pt;
    padding-right: 30pt;
}

.bottom_content {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 0.67vmax;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css">
        <title>Test test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="top_row">
                <div class="column" id="header_div">
                     <p class="top_text">Some text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="image_row">
                <div class="column" id="image_div">
                    <img class="image_content" src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="text_row_1">
                <div class="column" id="long_text_div">
                    <div class="text_content">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="text_row_2">
                <div class="column" id="short_text_div">
                    <div class="text_content">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="bottom_row">
                <div class="column" id="bottom_text_div">
                    <div class="bottom_content">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Still curious if this can be done without JS. Modifying existing html/css is fine as long as the current layout is preserved

Comment: I once again looked at your html structure .. No, you can't do this without js. Because your image and top text container are in different parent `.row` containers. My js code in the example is very small :)

Comment: ... but if you do like this - `.column { width: inherit; / * float: left; * / }`, and center your objects, then you get what you wanted, BUT here comes a new problem .. The proportions of the picture will not be imperfect. But again, you can reduce the `#image_row` height, then this is also a problem .. The height of the second `.row` will not be what you need. So use my example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all, to get the cleanest answer, you need to clean your codes and markup.

**What's wrong with your code?**

1. Do not use `display:table` to display what is NOT a table! Also, there are `flex` and `grid` that can build your page clean and simple, use them!
2. Using classes to say what things look like is WRONG! because the entire point of CSS is to allow for multiple appearances off of one markup. Using classes to say what the tag is/mean, is Also WRONG! Each tag has a meaning, use them properly. The “ideal” best HTML should require little to no modification for a complete reskin.
3. Stop using classes for nothing and endless pointless `div` for nothing! you want to style the `p`, then use `p/header p {}` in your CSS! how much is hard to use `p` instead of `text-top`? really? text-top? [Read more about 2 and 3 here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/news-flash-youve-probably-been-using-html-wrong-2dfb62755280).
4. Don't use `px`, use `em`.

> EM scales to the user preference so the user doesn’t have to zoom. If
> you use EM alongside fluid or semi-fluid design, your layout is less
> likely to break when zoomed. EM is multiplicative, so if you use it
> for all your measurements, you resize the parent and all the children
> change with it.

[Read more about it here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/scalable-styled-checkboxes-using-just-css-its-called-em-use-em-db21bae5f216).

So, it may not be the answer you are looking for, because I first cleaned up your codes and then applied what you wanted about that text, but anyway, take a look at the bottom solutions.

**How to solve your problem?**

Well as the text and image are in two different containers, we need to use some tricks.

**First solution:** use a `div` inside `header` as a width wrapper and set `max-width` of it, in the CSS.
As the height is constant, you can find the image max-width and use it to set the `div` wrapper. [take a look here in codepen about this solution](https://codepen.io/MohamadNR/pen/PoGpjXP).

**Second solution:** use the `calc()` to calculate the padding needed to align the text and image.
As the width of the image is constant while the container is larger than the image, the left, and right padding of the text can be obtained using: `calc((100% - {image width})/2)`. and while the container width is the same as the image or smaller, the above calculation returns 0 which is right. [Check it out on codepen.](https://codepen.io/MohamadNR/details/WNGpZgq)

How does that calculation work?

By subtraction 100% from the image width, the white space around the image obtains, and then by dividing it by 2, left and right padding obtains.

If you don't want to set the width manually and calculate it by height, which is not necessary and nonsense, then you can do it using the aspect ratio of the image.

**Bottom Line:**

If you don't insist on using a specified height, then you can use `div` in the first solution for both, or the same padding for both like solution 2.

Comment: Seems that most of your links point to your websites, or something you created

Comment: There are only two links that relates to my codepen nothing more! And, that articles are from Jason Knight, not mine!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to CSS so I could be wrong. But could it be something as simple as:

```css
position: relative;
right: 5px;
```

or possibly set position to fixed. But I think it sticks to one position on the screen then meaning scrolling wont work.